# Reverse for 'update_task' '('',)' not found

Tags: python, django, forms, view

Im new to programming, i started 3 weeks ago, so im very new and get lost really quick haha, so this project is for learning for my final app that i want to do, this is just one part of it.

Im trying to make a web where i can add products, that have specific atributes, like, name, family, type, price, etc.

This is the error i get :

> NoReverseMatch at /
>   Reverse for 'update_task' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['update_task\/(?P[^/]+)\/$']
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>   Django Version: 3.0.6
>   Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
>   Exception Value:
>   Reverse for 'update_task' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['update_task\/(?P[^/]+)\/$']
>   Exception Location: C:\Users\Fede\PycharmProjects\remito_wakanda_prueba_1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 677
>   Python Executable:  C:\Users\Fede\PycharmProjects\remito_wakanda_prueba_1\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>   Python Version: 3.6.8
>   Python Path:
>   ['C:\Users\Fede\PycharmProjects\remito_wakanda_prueba_1\remitowakandaprueba',
>    'C:\Users\Fede\PycharmProjects\remito_wakanda_prueba_1\venv\Scripts\python36.zip',
>    'C:\Users\Fede\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs',
>    'C:\Users\Fede\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib',
>    'C:\Users\Fede\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36',
>    'C:\Users\Fede\PycharmProjects\remito_wakanda_prueba_1\venv',
>    'C:\Users\Fede\PycharmProjects\remito_wakanda_prueba_1\venv\lib\site-packages']

and this is my code :

list.html :

```
<div class="center-column">

<form method="POST" action="/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.title}}
    <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="Añadir Producto">
</form>

<div class="todo-list">

       #task   #tasks
{% for producto in productos %}
    <div class="item-row">
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'update_task' productos.id %}">Modificar</a>
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete' productos.id %}">Borrar</a>

        {% if productos.complete == True %}
        <strike>{{productos}}</strike>
        {% else %}
        <span>{{productos}}</span>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
from .forms import *

def index(request):
productos = Productos.objects.all()
form = AñadirAlPedido()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AñadirAlPedido(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return redirect('/')

context = {'productos': productos, 'form': form}

return render(request, 'tasks/list.html', context)


def updateTask(request, pk):
productos = Productos.objects.get(id=pk)

form = AñadirAlPedido(instance=productos)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AñadirAlPedido(request.POST, instance=productos)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')

context = {'form': form}

return render(request, 'tasks/update_task.html', context)


def deleteTask(request,pk):
item = Productos.objects.get(id=pk)

context = {'item':item}

if request.method == 'POST':
    item.delete()
    return redirect('/')

return render(request, 'tasks/delete.html', context)
```

forms.py :

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *

# era TaskForm
class AñadirAlPedido(forms.ModelForm):
title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Añadir producto...'}))
class Meta: #era Task
    model = Productos
        #era '__all__'
    fields = ['aroma', 'tipo', 'linea']
```

Thanks in advance ♥

Comment: It is `producto.id`, not `productos.id` in `{% url 'update_task' ... %}` (same in delete).

Comment: Thanks man, can you explain why it should be producto and not productos ? the class is called productos

Comment: because you iterate with `{% for producto in productos %}`. `productos` is a *collection* of `Productos` objects, and a collection has no `.pk`/`.id`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation man ♥

Answer (score 0):

You must use `producto` instead of `productos` in `forloop` in template

```
{% for producto in producto s%}
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'update_task' producto.id %}">Modificar</a>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete' producto.id %}">
...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer man! now the page is up, but it does not do what i want it to do, could u help me a little ?

Comment: now it has a box where i can wirte , but i want to have a menu where i cant select the products and that those products adds into a detailed order

Comment: I couldn't understand. Could you explain more?

Comment: Yes, this is what i want to make, its better explained here, i dont know how to use forms to make this an actual web where i can order products like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61959620/how-do-i-make-an-order-products-app-like-this