# how do I make an "order" products app like this

Tags: python, django, model, product

My name is Federico

I need to make a system for my company, we sell perfumes, in a first stage I only need an app where people can choose between 5 perfumes types, when they chose the type, the have to choose the "family" of the perfume, and then the perfume itself (name of the perfume), and this perfumes have a price
so , for example: Perfume for pets (type) - puppys ("family") - citrus (the name of the scent) - 10 usd (price)

for understanding how it works, first I want to make a web where i can order the products and they add up in a detailed order where I can see the products, the price, the total, etc, standard stuff, so I need this to add up and store in a form i think.

I have created the class and they're like this :

```
from django.db import models


class TipoProducto(models.Model):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=20)
precio_mayorista = models.IntegerField(default=0)
precio_final = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.nombre


class LineaProducto(models.Model):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40)

def __str__(self):
    return self.nombre


class Productos(models.Model):
aroma = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
tipo = models.ForeignKey(TipoProducto, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
linea = models.ForeignKey(LineaProducto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.aroma
```

I would really apreciate if someone could help me to understand how can i make this "order" app , it does not need to connect to any stock for now, i just want to understand the basics

Sorry for my bad english, and thanks in advance for your help ♥

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've almost got it :)

The approach I would use would be:

```py
class Aroma(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class LineaProducto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class TipoProducto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    linea_producto = models.ForeignKey(LineaProducto, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Producto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    aromas = models.ManyToManyField(Aroma)
    tipo_producto = models.ForeignKey(TipoProducto, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    precio_mayorista = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    precio_final = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

The LineaProducto would be the "Type", The TipoProducto would be the "Family" and the Producto would be the product.

Hopefully this sets you in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks for the help man, im actually trying to make an app out of this, that does what i stated, but i dont seem to find an actual tutorial or something similar for this, could you point me in the rict direction ? how do I make this classes, into a web where i can add products and the products start to appear in the order and then finally theres a total (money) ?

Comment: Have you done any html programming before? If not you'll need to familiarise yourself as this is the current standard for displaying information in a web browser. If you are, then I'd suggest running through the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/